# C order of operations

Tags: c, scope, printf, operator-precedence

So for two separate code fragments, why does an incrementor/decrementor act differently?

Fragment A:

```
i=7; j=8; k=9; 
printf("%d\n", i - 7 && j++ > k);
printf("%d %d %d", i, j, k);
```

will produce the following output:

```
0
7 8 9
```

Fragment B:

```
while (i > 0)
printf("T minus %d and counting\n",i--);
```

produces this:

```
T minus 5 and counting
T minus 4 and counting
T minus 3 and counting
T minus 2 and counting
T minus 1 and counting
```

Now, I know that arguments to functions are passed by value, and that it must have something to do with the fact that `j` is used in a boolean expression. But these two situations seem contradictory to me. What's going on here?

Comment: I assume in Fragment B, `i` is initialized to 5? That output is expected if that is the case.

Comment: I think @grimetime is trying to say that he doesn't understand why `i--` decrements the value of i each time it is called, but `j++` doesn't change the value of j after it is called.

Comment: @sarnold: Actually, both `i` and `j`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, you're going to need to look *very* closely at how the operators precedences are arranged *and* exactly how they work.  Since this is homework, i'm not going to give the exact answer, but there are two things you should do.

1. Rewrite tthe expressions with full parentheses using the precedence tables
2. Look up the *exact* behavior of `&&`.  In particular, when is the subexpression `j++ > k` executed?

Answer (score 2):

It's called short circuiting. When the left hand of && evaluates to falsy the right hand side is not executed anymore (skipped).

Comment: Well, no, it's not optimized out -- this code would behave the same without the optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a short circuit acting here (&&).
Only the left side of the expression will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment A:

">" has more priority than "&&", so

```
printf("%d\n", i - 7 && j++ > k);
```

like this:

```
printf("%d\n", i - 7 && (j++ > k));
```

and "&&" is a Short circuit operation, because (i - 7) == 0, is FALSE, so (j++ > k) will be ignored, all of these three number is not changed.

Fragment B:

"i--" will return value original firstly, and then minus one.